# confused with CMD and ENTRYPOINT in dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have known that in the dockerfile, when ENTRYPOINT and CMD are both provided, the values in CMD will be as default parameter of ENTRYPOINT, then when running a container with additional parameter, the additional parameter will replace the values of CMD in dockerfile.

but when I see the dockerfile of mongodb, I'm confused, the entrypoint and cmd part of its dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

I know when I run `docker run mongo:latest` this will be `docker-entrypoint.sh mongod`, but when I run `docker run mongo:latest --auth`, why could it run correctly? Won't it be `docker-entrypoint.sh --auth`? since the `--auth` will replace `mongod`, so why I run `docker run mongo --auth` but it works fine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [mongod Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/812b8fb401a929c312c7222a26b707a6415450c6/3.4/Dockerfile) references [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/812b8fb401a929c312c7222a26b707a6415450c6/3.4/docker-entrypoint.sh).
That script [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/812b8fb401a929c312c7222a26b707a6415450c6/3.4/docker-entrypoint.sh) starts by testing if the first parameter begins with '`-`' (as in '`--auth`'):

```
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mongod "$@"
fi
```

So the arguments become `mongod --auth`, not just `--auth`.

Meaning:

- if you have to pass any argument *after* `mongod`, you don't have to type `mongod` first when using `docker run`: it will be added for you in `docker-entrypoint.sh`
- if you don't have any argument to pass after `mongod`, you don't have to type `mongod` either: `CMD` will provide it for you to the `ENTRYPOINT` `docker-entrypoint.sh`.